# Wrapping Generated Elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create this:

```
<label><input id=""><span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span></label>
```

This is my code:

```
$('.property .includes')
    .append('<label>').html(
        $('<input>').attr('id', this.id) +
        $('<span>').html(this.description)
    );
```

It doesn't seem to work, as it just says, "[Object] [Object]."

How can I create the code above?

Comment: The `.html` is going to work on `.property .includes` and not on `label`.

Comment: You're concatenating javascript objects ( $('some-sleector') is actually an object ) as strings, that's why javascript type-casts objects as [Object] and creates string '[Object]' + '[Object]'. As commenters already noticed you should use .append() instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to change your code to:

```
$('<label/>')
    .append( $('<input>').attr('id', this.id) )
    .append( $('<span>').html(this.description) )
    .appendTo('.property .includes');
```

I'm also pretty sure you are trying to append the span and input elements to the label element.

I have chosen to use [`.appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto) as well instead of nesting function calls:

```
$('.property .includes').append(
  $('<label/>')
    .append( $('<input>').attr('id', this.id) )
    .append( $('<span>').html(this.description) )
);
```

Comment: why not use: `.append( $('<input>').attr('id', this.id), $('<span>').html(this.description) )` ?

Comment: @NicoSantangelo Thats is more beautiful. Didn't even know that was posible. I must say that I'm not usually use `.append` that I like to use templates to create my DOM structure that I find it easier to maintain.

Comment: If you change the `.html()` to `.text()`, I'll give you an upvote…

Comment: @Bergi. Then i don't want your upvote. I havn't seen OP saying that `this.description` only contains text and not html fragments.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing the following:

```
var label = $("<label />").html(
    "<input id='" + this.id + "'>" +
    "<span>" + this.description + "</span>"
);
$('.property .includes').append( label );
```

Comment: Why "*should*"? And why do you mix DOM creation with innerHTML?

Answer (score 1):

Try using like below,

```
$('.property .includes').append(
           $('<label />').append($('<input />', {'id': this.id}))
                         .append($('<span />').html(this.description))
     );
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FJAjK/

Comment: You shouldn't pass jQuery objects to `.html()`

Answer (score 1):

mkoryak beat me to it.

```
    $('.property .include').append($('<label></label>')
                              .append($('<input></input>').attr('id', this.id))
                              .append($('<span></span>').html(this.description)));
```

Here's a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PQ6VM/2/) for it too